# Media Player doesn't play for the second time

Tags: java, android

I use same button for play and pause.It can handle play and pause smoothly.But after the music file end, it can not play it again.When I press it restart the application.I use mp.reset(); mp.release();.It doesn't help me in the case

Java Code:

```
final MediaPlayer mp1;

             mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(convertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(), convertView.getResources().getIdentifier(audiopath, "raw", convertView.getContext().getPackageName()));



            mHolder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    if (mp1.isPlaying()) {

                        mp1.pause();

                        mHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.plays);


                    } else {


                        mp1.start();
                        mHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                                mp.reset();
                                mp.release();


                                mHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.plays);



                            }




                        });




                    }




                }
            });
```

LogCat:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
    at com.example.package.adapter.AdapterN$3.onClick(AdapterN.java:223)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer]
[img ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)

### Problem

When you call `release()` of a `MediaPlayer`, it deallocates all its resources allocated with `MediaPlayer.create()` previously, hence no longer being accessible. This produces,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>       at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
>       at com.example.package.adapter.AdapterN$3.onClick(AdapterN.java:223)

### Solution

You should remove,

```
mp.release()
```

However, you can still use `release()` but in that case you have to again create `MediaPlayer` instance using,

```
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(convertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(), convertView.getResources().getIdentifier(audiopath, "raw", convertView.getContext().getPackageName()));
```

in proper place (i.e. before accessing any start, pause, reset etc.).

### Suggestions

1. Always create `MediaPlayer` instance in `onCreate()`.
2. Release MediaPlayer
   instance in `onDestroy()` Use in between.
3. Use `start/pause/reset` APIs in between create and release.

Comment: Thanks for help.But when I removed both mp.reset() and mp.release()  and the problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because of the "mp.release()":

As you can see in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer), it state that after release(), the object is no longer available.

So, what i would suggest here is you may just remove the "mp.release()" and put it under onDestroy() of your activity.